# Android Studio Import from Github Gradle Not Building Different Computer

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gradle

This one is frustrating I've gone through several StackOverflow threads and do not see a definitive answer to this within the last year, but I see the question has been posted prior to this and I can't see this as an optimal workflow.

Andriod Studio 3.0.1
Github as version control (https://github.com/CPWu/AndroidLabs/tree/Lab_2)

1. I create a project on machine X and use git to push the project to Github (Lab_2)
2. I decide on want to work on machine Y and install Android Studio and use Check Out Project from Version Control.
3. Would you like to create a Studio Project... I click Yes
4. I want to import project from external model, I select gradle option #1 (Why is there 2 shown?
5. Use default gradle wrapper(not configured for the current project) is grayed out. I could use local gradle distribution however the project will not build. I have tried creating a Sample Project and copying the gradle folder into this project and trying to reimport with no success. My understanding is that by default projects are created with a gradle wrapper (a prepackaged gradle to ensure projects build on all machines) this I do not believe is pushed up to git. Is having a gradle.properties - as shown in my github not sufficient to rebuild to the project? What is the best workflow to get this working properly?

Comment: "however the project will not build"... You should specify why not... Include errors. "I do not believe is pushed up to git"... It is pushed, unless it is explicitly ignored

Answer (score 0):

Your project does not adhere to a [standard Android Gradle project layout](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html#ProjectFiles)

You are missing the top level Gradle files that actually determine how the `app` module builds

```
app/
    src/
    build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

The wrapper is optional

Comment: Should this not be done automagically? Example: https://github.com/SuhuiXi/Android-Project browsed through github and their repository actually includes the gradle wrapper.

Comment: As I said, the wrapper is optional. The `.gitignore` doesn't exclude it